# How Overloaded operator new is internally works?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, new-operator

As the example given below, overloaded operator new is returning void pointer

```
void* Myclass::operator new(size_t size)
{
    void *storage = malloc(size);
    if(NULL == storage) {
            throw "allocation fail : no free memory";
    }
    return storage;
}
```

But my calling like this `MyClass *x = new MyClass;`.

So the question is how that new operator knows that which type of pointer in its left hand side. to be typecasted.

Question 2: What happen if I write MyClass *ptr = new Derived();? it is necessary to overload new operator in both derived as well as in base class?

Comment: The operator doesn't have to know, the compiler will add extra code for calling the class constructor and assign the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `new MyClass` then the compiler *knows* you are allocating an instance of `MyClass` and do whatever is needed to handle the allocation, like looking up an overloaded `new` operator in the class, and do the "type casting".

And in the overloaded operator function you *know* that it has been called when allocating a `MyClass` object.